# How to add custom list into listview control?

Tags: android

I have a problem binding a listview with ArrayList. When the first Vegetable Category is clicked it should bring different 3 elements in the listview but only the first one is displayed on the listview the others didn't show up.

here is my code (I am new to android stuff)!!!!!!

it should bring the list like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8OZC.png)

problem_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/problem_imageView"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp" />
<!--app:srcCompat="@drawable/pest" />-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/englishName_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/problem_imageView"
    android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/problem_imageView"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:text="Category English Name"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/amharicName_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/englishName_textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/englishName_textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:text="Amharic Name"
    android:textColor="#000080"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/count_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/amharicName_textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/amharicName_textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:text="Count"
    android:textColor="#000080"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

ProblemAdapter.java

```
package com.packageName;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class ProblemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Integer> listID;
private ArrayList<String> English_Title;
private ArrayList<String> Amharic_Title;
private ArrayList<Integer> count;

public ProblemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> listID, 
ArrayList<String> name,ArrayList<String> Amharic_Title,ArrayList<Integer> 
count) {

    this.context = context;
    this.listID = listID;
    this.English_Title = name;
    this.Amharic_Title= Amharic_Title;
    this.count = count;
 }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return English_Title.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {


    return position;

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.problem_list, null);
    } else {

        ImageView img =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.problem_imageView);
        TextView txtView_Eng =  
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.englishName_textView);
        //TextView txtView_Amc =  
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.amharicName_textView);
        TextView txtView_Count =  
   convertView.findViewById(R.id.count_textView);

        img.setImageResource(listID.get(position));
        txtView_Eng.setText(English_Title.get(position));
        txtView_Amc.setText(Amharic_Title.get(position));
        txtView_Count.setText(count.get(position));

    }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

problem_category.java

```
package com.packageName;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class problem_category extends AppCompatActivity {

String VegetableCategoryType ;

ListView listView;
ArrayList<Integer> ImageID;
ArrayList<String> English_Title;
ArrayList<String> Amharic_Title;
ArrayList<Integer> count;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_problem_category);

    // Assigning caller plant to the VegetableCategoryType
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    VegetableCategoryType = intent.getStringExtra("Plant_Name");


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) 
    findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Will be replaced with new action", 
     Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    listView =  findViewById(R.id.category_List_view);

    ImageID  = new ArrayList<>();
    English_Title = new ArrayList<>();
    Amharic_Title = new ArrayList<>();
    count = new ArrayList<>();

    ImageID = getImageID();
    English_Title = getEnglishName();
    Amharic_Title = getAmharicName();
     count = getCount();

    ProblemAdapter pAdapter = new ProblemAdapter(problem_category.this,
    ImageID,English_Title,Amharic_Title,count);
    listView.setAdapter(pAdapter);

    }




@Override
public void finish(){
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_right);
}

public ArrayList<String> getEnglishName(){
    English_Title= new ArrayList<>();

    English_Title.add("Pest");
    English_Title.add("Disease");
    English_Title.add("Disorder");

    return English_Title;
}

private ArrayList<String> getAmharicName() {
    Amharic_Title= new ArrayList<>();

    Amharic_Title.add("sub-title1");
    Amharic_Title.add("sub-title2");
    Amharic_Title.add("sub-title3");

    return Amharic_Title;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getImageID(){

    ImageID = new ArrayList<>();

    ImageID.add(R.drawable.pest);
    ImageID.add(R.drawable.disease);
    ImageID.add(R.drawable.disorder_edited);

    return ImageID;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getCount(){

    count = new ArrayList<>();

    if(VegetableCategoryType == "Cabbage"){
        count.add(3);
        count.add(8);
        count.add(3);


    }else if (VegetableCategoryType =="Pepper"){

        count.add(7);
        count.add(5);
        count.add(2);
    }else if(VegetableCategoryType == "Onion"){

        count.add(2);
        count.add(5);
        count.add(3);
    }else if(VegetableCategoryType == "Tomato"){
        count.add(8);
        count.add(16);
        count.add(5);
    }

    return count;
   }


}
```

MainActivity click_Listners()

```
 public void click_Listeners(){
    cabbageImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent pCategory = new 
     Intent(getApplicationContext(),problem_category.class);
            pCategory.putExtra("Plant_Name","Cabbage");
            startActivity(pCategory);

   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: image not showing up ?

Comment: # John Joe the images are displayed correctly!! sorry how can i help?

Comment: I see three items here https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMkC2.png. What is not showing up?

Comment: # John Joe the second and third list should have different Image, Name, Amharic name and count. that is the problem.

Comment: Did your problem solved ?

Comment: Nop!! still trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the values for the new views created. Your getView body should look like this:

```
if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.problem_list, null);
    } else {

        ImageView img =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.problem_imageView);
        TextView txtView_Eng =  
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.englishName_textView);
        //TextView txtView_Amc =  
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.amharicName_textView);
        TextView txtView_Count =  
   convertView.findViewById(R.id.count_textView);

        img.setImageResource(listID.get(position));
        txtView_Eng.setText(English_Title.get(position));
        txtView_Amc.setText(Amharic_Title.get(position));
        txtView_Count.setText(count.get(position));

    }

    return convertView;
```

Comment: same problem showing. do i have to loop through and add the list items??

Comment: Also If you set an integer as text in a textview, it treats it as a resource id. You have to convert the integer to a string before you set it as text like this txtView_Count.setText(String.valueOf(count.get(position)));

Comment: Thanks for the conversion that you point out. but the compiler says 'class  ViewHolder is never used'  how can i correct it and obtain the desired output. Thanks!!

Comment: Remove the ViewHolder class. You don't need it.